# Is it possible to apply analyzers in DB index

Tags: database, elasticsearch

In elastic-search, we can apply analyzers for indexing.

And I need to know in DB can we apply analyzers or any other technique while indexing

Comment: SQL Server was probably the first database to offer analyzers with v7, back in 1997. Go to `Tools > Database Tuning Advisor`, or select a query, right-click and select `Analyze Query in Database Tuning Advisor` from the context menu

Comment: Simply displaying the execution plan of a query (Ctrl+L) will show a warning if the optimizer thinks the query would benefit from a new index.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server was probably the first database to offer analyzers with v7, back in 1997. The feature was called `Query Analyzer` in the past, now it's [Database Tuning Advisor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231122.aspx). It was also one of the first if no the first to combine heuristics and cost-based analysis to find indexes to create or drop.

You can run the analyzer over the queries in the current window, a set of statements, a captured trace, or select a specific query and analyze it. Analyzing a captured trace is one of the best ways to find new indexes or drop those that are too expensive for a production system.

DTA can propose indexes, filtered indexes, indexed views, filtered indexes, partitions and statistics. It will also propose to drop indexes whose cost is greater than their benefit

DTA is a separate executable but you can also access it from the "Tools > Database Tuning Advisor" menu in SQL Server Management Studio. To analyze a single query, select the query text, right-click and select Analyze Query in Database Tuning Advisor from the context menu

You'll find a detailed tutorial [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166575.aspx)

You can also find new indexes if you display a query's execution plan. The query optimizer display a warning over the plan if it thinks that a specific index would improve the query's performance. Right-clicking on the warning will create the actual index script.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's very useful for me